# How can I modify the regular expression that reads vectors to read matrices?

Tags: java, regex, matrix, vector, token

I have the following regex that reads arrays of any size like {1.0, 2, 3, 5.4}:

```
"\\{\\s*((-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+(\\s*,\\s*(-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+)*\\s*)?\\}"
```

How can I modify it in such a way that it will read matrices of any dimension like: {{1.2, 3,4},{2,3.4,3}} etc?

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to add the outer curly braces and make the existing pattern repeated with an optional comma:
prefix:   {(. 
          The outer curly brace and a opening parentheses so the existing regex can be repeated.

```
"\\{\\s*((-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+(\\s*,\\s*(-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+)*\\s*)?\\}"
```

append: ,?)+}. 
     a comma - the question mark makes it optional
     then close the parentheses and allow for it to repeat 1 or more times
     and finally the ending outer curly brace

put it together and add the escaping needed to get:

```
"\\{(\\{\\s*((-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+(\\s*,\\s*(-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+)*\\s*)?\\},?)+\\}"
```

Answer (score 1):

To make it more readable, your regex can be written as

```
String numRegex = "(-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+";
String regex = "\\{\\s*(" + numRegex + "(\\s*,\\s*" + numRegex + ")*\\s*)?\\}";
```

Though I do believe the `numRegex` part is incorrect, because it allows text such as `1/2-3.4/5-6/7`

Now you want to wrapper that in an `{ xxx , xxx , ... }` construct, so

```
String regex2 = "\\{\\s*(" + regex + "(\\s*,\\s*" + regex + ")*\\s*)?\\}";
```

*Test*

```
System.out.println("{{1.2, 3,4},{2,3.4,3}}".matches(regex2));
System.out.println("{{1.2, 3,4},{2,3.4,3},}".matches(regex2));
```

*Output*

```
true
false
```

As a single long regex that would be

```
"\\{\\s*(\\{\\s*((-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+(\\s*,\\s*(-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+)*\\s*)?\\}(\\s*,\\s*\\{\\s*((-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+(\\s*,\\s*(-?\\b\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?(?:/\\d+(?:\\.\\d+)?)?\\b)+)*\\s*)?\\})*\\s*)?\\}"
```

but it's so much easier to read if you can split and build it like above.